# Access Complex Json value from URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am trying to access the JSON content from the below URL and parse to extract and print the date  value of "data.content.containers.container.locationDateTime"

iff the

"data.content.containers.container.label " has been set as "Empty Equipment Returned"

```
$url = 'https://elines.coscoshipping.com/ebtracking/public/containers/FCIU5238624';
$datax = file_get_contents($url);
$x = json_decode($datax);
```

could anyone help me please

Comment: You need to refine the question more. Do you want to do this on  server side or client side? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Your question is tagged JavaScript yet code is PHP, it's unclear what the question is, exactly.

Comment: @Matt I am trying to get this done at client side

Comment: @chaoz Basically I am trying to print the locationDateTime

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract and access data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-to-extract-and-access-data-from-json-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is work for me to extract and print the date value

```
$url = 'https://elines.coscoshipping.com/ebtracking/public/containers/FCIU5238624';
$datax = file_get_contents($url);
$x = json_decode($datax);
$dataTime = $x->data->content->containers[0]->container->locationDateTime;
print $dataTime;
```

Comment: That's server side fyi.